# How to enable news pane at start state in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017 when you start VS (no solution loaded) there is a pane with news shown at start.

How to enable this news pane in VS 2019?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a 2nd way to show the old start page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft removed this start page in favor of the new [start Window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/get-to-code-how-we-designed-the-new-visual-studio-start-window/)

[image]

In the VS 2019 option you have the 3 what you want:

- the new Start Windows
- empty environment
- last loaded solution

Unofficially I got it back by using the 3rd party addon [RevDeBug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RevDeBug.RecordReplayforNET-RevDeBug) which has an option to start it's own start page which is similar to the old start page from former VS versions:

[image]

Here you also see your recent project, can open/create solution and on right side you have developer news feed.

When you don't want to use **RevDeBug** you can install the extension [VSStart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JonDavis.VSStart)

> Auto-launches the Start Page or executes another VS shell command at
>   startup in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

[image]

[Start Page on startup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JanKucera.StartPageOnStartup) does the same like VSStart, but also does some hacks to get Developer News working again.

In VS 2019 Update 2 (16.2) Microsoft starts removing more parts of Start Page, so that the extension could stop working soon.